# How to setup ImageMagick7 in the android project

Tags: java, android, imagemagick

I tried to install [ImageMgaick library for android](https://github.com/cherryleafroad/Android-ImageMagick7) but It gives errors like sometime some .so file not found or virtual method invokes. I would be misplacing or missing some process like build .mk files. I read the README.md but it is bit confusing as for those who do not get involve in building from source and binaries. I want to to use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) for resizing and conversion of gif/animataed webp files. I tried it's CLI tool and it gives expected output so I want to implement it in android.

So How to implement the [ImageMgaick-Android](https://github.com/cherryleafroad/Android-ImageMagick7)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site works best when you specify in detail what steps you took and what error(s) were generated.

Comment: Adding a link to the same repository doesn't help. If the English is confusing better to quote a section of the README and state what is unclear. Also please read: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)